# Application window is still visible after suspend and shutdown livecycle event

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10, c++-cx

When i run my application under debugger and trigger "suspend and shutdown" livecycle event On_Suspending event handler gets executed and then process immediately exits (without crashing or any visible errors). Event loop CoreDispatcher::ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessUntilQuit) is not interrupted so IFrameworkView::Run method never exits and IFrameworkView::Uninitialize or destructor are never called. And (what is more confusing) application window is still visible! As i figured out with Spy++ it actually belongs to ApplicationFrameHost process. Interacting with it may spawn new application process.

I've tried executing CoreWindow::Close() at On_Suspending event handler, but it causes exception ("WinRT information: Closing main window is not allowed.") to be thrown.

This behavior can be reproduced with many DirectX samples from MS.

Is "suspend and shutdown" broken somehow or does using it require some preconditions or maybe it can not be used with non-xaml applications?

Comment: When you are debugging and you are switching between the life cycles from Visual Studio, the app's window is not closed. That's how it works in debug. However when not debugging it will work as expected.

Comment: Since application window is not closed i thought that something goes wrong during shutdown process. But if it is not the case then why aren't Uninitialize and destructors called? I do realize that uwp applications can be silently terminated but i want to debug a proper exit sequence. Maybe it would be better to try and squeeze all the important uninitialization operations into On_Suspending event handler?

Comment: Ok, now I've tested it in VS 2017 and it seems that the "Suspend and Shutdown" may really be broken because it behaves differently than it used to before..

Comment: Anyway it's not a great idea to unitialize everything in the On_Suspending event handler, because the app may be suspended only when user minimizes it and that may happen really often and you will be just unitializing and initializing your app over and over.. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) may help you..